# c - UDP client-server with multiple clients

Tags: c, sockets, udp, named-pipes

OK, here's the situation.
I need to build a client-server using UDP.

The server must run a third program and pipe it to the client (I already did this app with TCP and Named Pipes, and I just 'dupped' the file descriptors of the fifo or socket to the child running the third program).

The problem comes in udp, I can't dup the socket, as it may be used for multiple clients (and the application must be unique for each client), so I'm kinda stucked.

I was thinking of using named pipes between server and child
(so the client would send to server, server writes on fifo, child responds on fifo, server responds to client. using for instance the client ip as a fifo name, so  it can be easy to identify).

Problem is if I dup the fifo on child, I wouldn't be able to close and reopen the fifo on server (which I would need to do with each message received)...

Is there any way around this? I'd liked to keep it as simple as possible.

**EDIT**
ok, I kinda made it work (it ain't pretty though).

I made it so that the flow is as follows:
client -> server -> pipe for that client (if it does not exist, a child is created and the pipe for that child is added) -> child -> pipe -> server -> client

the pipe structure is this:

```
typedef struct _pipes{
    char ip_client[SIZE_IP];
    int fd_read;
    int fd_write;
    int child_pid;
    struct _pipes *next;
} pipes;
```

when a message is recieved (recvfrom), I search for a pipe with that IP, if not found, create a pipe, fork and complete the structure (and add it to the list).

Comment: Is there one child program spawned by the server for each client, or just a single child for all clients?  What is the data flow like?  I understand most of what you're asking but the details are not very clear yet.

Comment: one child per client (the child makes dup to replace stdin and stdout, and then execles)

client -> server -> pipe_for_child-client -> child -> pipe -> server -> client

I am currently trying to connect each child with the server by pipes (2 pipes per child), for this I had to create a list like this:
    
 typedef struct _pipes{
  char ip_client[SIZE_IP];
  int fd_read;
  int fd_write;
  int child_pid;
  struct _pipes *next;
 } pipes; 
I haven't discarded this possibility yet, but I ain't sure it will work, and I am sure it ain't pretty

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the UDP server uses a single socket to communicate with all its clients.  It doesn't have to be this way.  For example, you could have a single socket which clients can connect to, but only use it to establish a "session" which would continue on a new socket created by the server.

You could also do things a bit more manually, by having the server use the "from" address (e.g. via `recvfrom()`) to discriminate the clients, dispatch the message to the correct child process, and then return the results to the originating client (e.g. via `sendto()`).

In fact, you may have to use the second option due to the nature of UDP.  For example, if the child program writes over 1500 bytes at once, that will not all fit in a single UDP datagram, so will be silently truncated.  That would be bad, so you may need to add logic in your server to fragment the data before sending to the client.

Comment: I am using this functions, the problem was to link them as stdin/out of the child created by the server (I am trying to solve this by creating pipes for each client-child, connecting them through a list in the server). I think this just may be working. If so, I edit with the answer